# Combine files records with repeated ID in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I have another case where I don't know how to find a solution with BizTalk.

I have this two flat files (in real there are 9 files to combine) and the output must be like shown in the picture:
[image]

How can I combine files which ID repeat several times in the main file.

In the below picture, the main file is "People". Is there way to do this without writing any code in BizTalk, or must I store this data in SQL DB after that i join them with a stored procedure?

Can you help me lay-out the steps I need to take, because I know how to combine files together but that is without the repeated ID's.

Comment: Doing it in SQL is a possibility.  However how often do the files come through?  Any chance of multiple batches files being processed at once?  Then you will need some sort of batch key to associate the files in the DB.

Comment: Files must come approximately at the same time and once a week. In my Orchestration I have parallel shape, with correlation. And when file receives it divides into messages row by row.  The key for combining files are mentioned in the picture in green. In this case there is a many-to-one relation. With keys which have unique ID's I can combine with that field correlation. But in this case I don't know how to build orchestration where all files can wait to each other and how to combine them. And when files receives how can I store them in DB as tables?